# Soundcloud API Returning 404 Not Found Error on Publicly Available Tracks

Tags: soundcloud

Here is the example

Track URL  : https://soundcloud.com/bingoplayers/hysteria-radio-056

This track exist on SoundCloud and publicly available

Resolve api url :

```
http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?url=https://soundcloud.com/bingoplayers/hysteria-radio-056&client_id={client_id}
```

APIs Response :

```
response : 
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "error_message": "404 - Not Found"
        }
    ]
}
```

Checked with different Client IDs and returning the same response every time.  Other tracks are working fine with same Client Ids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is a 302 as stated here
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#resolve

Your browser is redirecting. Run this via curl on your terminal and you would see the raw response

(if you still see an error, it's probably because it is paywalled content)

Comment: I am agree with you. I am using PHP cURL code for this..